How to generate C# client from Azure DevOps OpenAPI document with NSwag?
I'm trying to use NSwag to generate a client for the Azure DevOps REST API but I've hit a problem with deserializing the response.
I am using an OpenAPI document taken from here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/tree/master
Specifically the document for git: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/blob/master/specification/git/7.2/git.json
The problem seems to me to stem from the difference in what the specification claims is returned verses what's actually returned.
The spec states that the GetRepositories method returns an array of GitRepository. But when invoked, it actually returns a single object with one value property that then contains the array.
{
    "value":[{
        "id":"1234",
        "name":"bla blah"
    }]
}

So the code that NSwag generates is failing to deserialize it because it's not an array.
Generated line of code in question:
var typedBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseText, JsonSerializerSettings);

At runtime, T is System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<RestClients.GitRepository>.
Which leads to:
Could not deserialize the response body string as System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[RestClients.GitRepository, GeneratedRestClients, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].

Why would the specification document differ from what's actually returned?
And is there a way to tweak the NSwag settings so that it deserializes correctly?
Please keep in mind that the line of code that throws the exception is generated by NSwag. I know why it fails and if it were my own code I would know how to fix it (it's trying to deserialize to the wrong type). The question is about why the OpenAPI doc doesn't appear to match the actual content returned and how (if at all) we can use NSwag to generate a client for it.

Just out of curiosity, have you considered using the Azure DevOps .NET client libraries instead of creating your own client?

Can you share a minimal code snippet that reproduces the issue?

@RuiJarimba - To be honest, my original reason for using the DevOps API has come and gone. And I could have knocked up my own client code 10 times over in the time I've spent looking at this.
I only really want to know if the specification document is fundamentally wrong, or if this situation is quite normal and there's a simple NSwag setting that would deal with the situation that I've just missed.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT - I've included the actal line that throws the exception. But please keep in mind that it's generated by NSwag and the question is about how to use NSwag to generate a working client from the given OpenAPI document.

How did you get the responseText? If you output responseText directly, is there detailed information?

By using a breakpoint before the exception.
The json is in the format as above (I've just removed the detail).

"The problem seems to me to stem from the difference in what the specification claims is returned verses what's actually returned." - It's suggested to create an issue to confirm whether the document is wrong or there is something missing.
